# copy LONGTEXT from MySQL to CITEXT in PostgreSQL using Python

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql, pygresql

I have data in MySQL table which I want to copy to a PostgreSQL table.
Everything works except when the MySQL contains a string with `"` and/or `'`

For example: 
The data in MySQL:

[image]

When I run my code I get:

```
ProgrammingError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "t"
```

(the t of the can't)

This is my code:

```
postgre = pg.connect(dbname=DB,user=USR,passwd=PASSWD,host=HOST, port=PORT)
crs = db_remote.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
crs.execute ("""select post_id, post_excerpt from tabl""")
data = crs.fetchall ()
for row in data :  
    postgre.query("""INSERT INTO importfrommysql(id,message)
    VALUES ('%s','%s')"""%(row["post_id"],row["post_excerpt"]))
```

the connection `pg.connect` is from `PygreSQL` package.
What can I do? Is it possible to get the text as it is? or the only solution is to drop all `"` / `'` before the insert?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Psycopg](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/) `cursor.execute` parameter passing:

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(database='DB')
cursor = conn.cursor()

for row in data :

    cursor.execute ("""
        INSERT INTO importfrommysql (id,message)
        VALUES (%s,%s)
        """,
        (row["post_id"],row["post_excerpt"])
    )
```

It will escape and quote as necessary.

Comment: @ban Probably yes but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: is this way also secure against SQL injections?